# Logstash update field value based on reference variable

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

Using Logstash, I'm parsing a log file that contains a timestamp value every time a new process starts. Each process starts and logs its own run time starting from 0 to the time the process completes. I'm trying to visualize this in Kibana, and would like to be able to update the process time to the real-time timestamp being logged for that process.

Sample Input:

```
12:00:00 Process A starts: 
     0:00:01 Step 1
     0:00:04 Step 2
     ........
     0:10:01 Process Ends
%Random Log lines of no interest
12:10:05 Process B starts:
     0:00:01 Step 1
     0:00:04 Step 2
     ........
     0:10:01 Process Ends
.........
```

I'd like to parse this such that each timestamp is updated with the starting timestamp of the process.

Sample Output:

```
12:00:00 Process A starts: 
     12:00:01 Step 1
     12:00:04 Step 2
     ........
     12:10:01 Process Ends
%Random Log lines of no interest
12:10:05 Process B starts:
     12:10:06 Step 1
     12:10:09 Step 2
     ........
     12:20:06 Process Ends
.........
```

Is there any way to store this reference value and update these fields accordingly in Logstash or Elasticsearch? I'm working with the full ELK stack at the moment so any leads would be great.